# Select the first row returned from the join query based on a condition

Tags: sql-server, oracle, join

I have 2 tables PRODUCT and MANUFACTURER

Table1: PRODUCT, Columns: PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME

Table2: MANUFACTURER, Columns: PRODUCT_ID,MANF_ID,ITEM_NO,DEFAULT_MANF

I have to select the default manufacture of a product from the MANUFACTURER table. If no default manufacture is available, i will select a manufacturer by the ITEM_NO from the MANUFACTURER table.

I have written query for this as below:

```
SELECT p.PRODUCT_ID, p.PRODUCT_NAME, m.MANF_ID, m.ITEM_NO, m.DEFAULT_MANF 
FROM PRODUCT p 
INNER JOIN MANUFACTURER m on p.PRODUCT_ID = m.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE p.PRODUCT_ID = 'PROD001' 
AND m.MANF_ID = (SELECT TOP 1 MANF_ID FROM MANUFACTURER man WHERE man.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID and coalesce(man.DEFAULT_MANF, 'N') = 'Y' ORDER BY man.DEFAULT_MANF, man.MANF_ID )
```

This query works as expected in SQL Server, but on Oracle it wont work as I am using 'TOP' in the query.

Is there any way I can modify the query to work in both SQL Server and Oracle?

Comment: "Database Agnostic Code" is a myth.  I wouldn't even try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of Oracle is 12 or above, you can use `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` [(doc link)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABBADDD):

```
SELECT p.PRODUCT_ID, p.PRODUCT_NAME, m.MANF_ID, m.ITEM_NO, m.DEFAULT_MANF 
FROM PRODUCT p 
INNER JOIN MANUFACTURER m on p.PRODUCT_ID = m.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE p.PRODUCT_ID = 'PROD001' 
AND m.MANF_ID = (SELECT MANF_ID FROM MANUFACTURER man WHERE man.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID and coalesce(man.DEFAULT_MANF, 'N') = 'Y' ORDER BY man.DEFAULT_MANF, man.MANF_ID FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY)
```

If you're on Oracle 11 or below you need to use `rownum=1` instead.

I'll add that if your schema was designed properly there would only be one default manufacturer for a product, and the subquery wouldn't be needed.

To actually answer your question though, you can abuse `row_number`.

```
SELECT p.PRODUCT_ID, p.PRODUCT_NAME, m.MANF_ID, m.ITEM_NO, m.DEFAULT_MANF 
FROM PRODUCT p 
INNER JOIN MANUFACTURER m on p.PRODUCT_ID = m.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE p.PRODUCT_ID = 'PROD001' 
AND m.MANF_ID = (  
    SELECT MANF_ID FROM (
        SELECT MANF_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY man.DEFAULT_MANF, man.MANF_ID) as RN  
        FROM MANUFACTURER man 
        WHERE man.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID 
        and coalesce(man.DEFAULT_MANF, 'N') = 'Y'
    ) HACK
    WHERE RN=1
);
```

Comment: I don't think `fetch first rows` works on SQL Server.

Comment: thanks phil for the suggestion, but can we rewrite the Query in such a way that both Oracle and SQL server supports, I am using Oracle 11 and SQL server 2012 version

Comment: Oh, sorry. Brainfart, I just answered for Oracle. The proper way to do this is in your specific situation is to look and see if there's only ever one default manufacturer per product (as there would be in a decent design). If there is, you only need the filter condition (moved from the subquery to the main query) and don't need the inner select.

Comment: @jos.mathew123 answer updated